# Qt 5.12.1 MSVC Static Build .qmake.super

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, qmake

After building Qt 5.12.1 static using MSVC 2015, I can successfully build all of my Qt projects except one that includes the svg module. Running qmake on that project produces *Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: svg*

If I move the project under the Qt build path (i.e. QTDIR/my-project) it builds fine. Alternatively, if I copy the file, QTDIR/.qmake.super, into the root of my project, I can also build fine.

So, it appears that to build with the svg module, I need the .qmake.super file in the project's path hierarchy. Perhaps I have missed a step, or need to define an additional environment variable.

Here's my configure command:

```
configure ^
    -static ^
    -opensource ^
    -confirm-license ^
    -nomake tests ^
    -nomake examples ^
    -debug-and-release ^
    -platform win32-msvc2015 ^
    -openssl-linked -I %OPENSSL_DIR%\include -L %OPENSSL_DIR%\lib
```

Adding contents of .qmake.super:

```
QTREPOS += C:/Qt/x64/qtbase
QMAKEMODULES += C:/Qt/x64/qtbase/mkspecs/modules
QTREPOS += C:/Qt/x64/qtnetworkauth
QMAKEMODULES += C:/Qt/x64/qtnetworkauth/mkspecs/modules
QTREPOS += C:/Qt/x64/qtmacextras
QMAKEMODULES += C:/Qt/x64/qtmacextras/mkspecs/modules
QTREPOS += C:/Qt/x64/qtx11extras
QMAKEMODULES += C:/Qt/x64/qtx11extras/mkspecs/modules
QTREPOS += C:/Qt/x64/qtandroidextras
QMAKEMODULES += C:/Qt/x64/qtandroidextras/mkspecs/modules
QTREPOS += C:/Qt/x64/qtserialport
QMAKEMODULES += C:/Qt/x64/qtserialport/mkspecs/modules
QTREPOS += C:/Qt/x64/qtserialbus
QMAKEMODULES += C:/Qt/x64/qtserialbus/mkspecs/modules
QTREPOS += C:/Qt/x64/qtimageformats
QMAKEMODULES += C:/Qt/x64/qtimageformats/mkspecs/modules
QTREPOS += C:/Qt/x64/qtactiveqt
QMAKEMODULES += C:/Qt/x64/qtactiveqt/mkspecs/modules
QTREPOS += C:/Qt/x64/qtsvg
QMAKEMODULES += C:/Qt/x64/qtsvg/mkspecs/modules
QTREPOS += C:/Qt/x64/qtdeclarative
QMAKEMODULES += C:/Qt/x64/qtdeclarative/mkspecs/modules
QTREPOS += C:/Qt/x64/qtremoteobjects
QMAKEMODULES += C:/Qt/x64/qtremoteobjects/mkspecs/modules
QTREPOS += C:/Qt/x64/qtscxml
QMAKEMODULES += C:/Qt/x64/qtscxml/mkspecs/modules
QTREPOS += C:/Qt/x64/qtpurchasing
QMAKEMODULES += C:/Qt/x64/qtpurchasing/mkspecs/modules
QTREPOS += C:/Qt/x64/qtcanvas3d
QMAKEMODULES += C:/Qt/x64/qtcanvas3d/mkspecs/modules
QTREPOS += C:/Qt/x64/qtwebsockets
QMAKEMODULES += C:/Qt/x64/qtwebsockets/mkspecs/modules
QTREPOS += C:/Qt/x64/qtwebglplugin
QMAKEMODULES += C:/Qt/x64/qtwebglplugin/mkspecs/modules
QTREPOS += C:/Qt/x64/qtwebchannel
QMAKEMODULES += C:/Qt/x64/qtwebchannel/mkspecs/modules
QTREPOS += C:/Qt/x64/qtgamepad
QMAKEMODULES += C:/Qt/x64/qtgamepad/mkspecs/modules
QTREPOS += C:/Qt/x64/qt3d
QMAKEMODULES += C:/Qt/x64/qt3d/mkspecs/modules
QTREPOS += C:/Qt/x64/qtwayland
QMAKEMODULES += C:/Qt/x64/qtwayland/mkspecs/modules
QTREPOS += C:/Qt/x64/qtconnectivity
QMAKEMODULES += C:/Qt/x64/qtconnectivity/mkspecs/modules
QTREPOS += C:/Qt/x64/qtsensors
QMAKEMODULES += C:/Qt/x64/qtsensors/mkspecs/modules
QTREPOS += C:/Qt/x64/qtgraphicaleffects
QMAKEMODULES += C:/Qt/x64/qtgraphicaleffects/mkspecs/modules
QTREPOS += C:/Qt/x64/qtquickcontrols2
QMAKEMODULES += C:/Qt/x64/qtquickcontrols2/mkspecs/modules
QTREPOS += C:/Qt/x64/qtquickcontrols
QMAKEMODULES += C:/Qt/x64/qtquickcontrols/mkspecs/modules
QTREPOS += C:/Qt/x64/qtlocation
QMAKEMODULES += C:/Qt/x64/qtlocation/mkspecs/modules
QTREPOS += C:/Qt/x64/qtxmlpatterns
QMAKEMODULES += C:/Qt/x64/qtxmlpatterns/mkspecs/modules
QTREPOS += C:/Qt/x64/qtmultimedia
QMAKEMODULES += C:/Qt/x64/qtmultimedia/mkspecs/modules
QTREPOS += C:/Qt/x64/qtspeech
QMAKEMODULES += C:/Qt/x64/qtspeech/mkspecs/modules
QTREPOS += C:/Qt/x64/qtvirtualkeyboard
QMAKEMODULES += C:/Qt/x64/qtvirtualkeyboard/mkspecs/modules
QTREPOS += C:/Qt/x64/qtdatavis3d
QMAKEMODULES += C:/Qt/x64/qtdatavis3d/mkspecs/modules
QTREPOS += C:/Qt/x64/qtcharts
QMAKEMODULES += C:/Qt/x64/qtcharts/mkspecs/modules
QTREPOS += C:/Qt/x64/qtwinextras
QMAKEMODULES += C:/Qt/x64/qtwinextras/mkspecs/modules
QTREPOS += C:/Qt/x64/qttools
QMAKEMODULES += C:/Qt/x64/qttools/mkspecs/modules
QTREPOS += C:/Qt/x64/qtscript
QMAKEMODULES += C:/Qt/x64/qtscript/mkspecs/modules
QTREPOS += C:/Qt/x64/qtwebengine
QMAKEMODULES += C:/Qt/x64/qtwebengine/mkspecs/modules
QTREPOS += C:/Qt/x64/qtwebview
QMAKEMODULES += C:/Qt/x64/qtwebview/mkspecs/modules
QTREPOS += C:/Qt/x64/qttranslations
QMAKEMODULES += C:/Qt/x64/qttranslations/mkspecs/modules
QTREPOS += C:/Qt/x64/qtdoc
QMAKEMODULES += C:/Qt/x64/qtdoc/mkspecs/modules
QTREPOS += C:/Qt/x64/qtqa
QMAKEMODULES += C:/Qt/x64/qtqa/mkspecs/modules
```

Comment: `.qmake.super` is an ordinary text file, like, for example, `.qmake.stash`. What is its contents?

Comment: As you can see, the file contains absolute paths to all the Qt modules. I was able to get my project to build with a .qmake.super containing just one line `QMAKEMODULES += C:/Qt/x64/qtsvg/mkspecs/modules` So the issue appears to be svg module specific.

Comment: Well, you don't have to have `.qmake.super` at all, if you add the following lines to your .pro: `QMAKEMODULES *= C:/Qt/x64/qtsvg/mkspecs/modules` and `cache(QMAKEMODULES, set transient super)`. Although, it's still a question why it doesn't get added automatically inside the startup script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple fix: specify a prefix in the config and then nmake install. The installed build doesn't need .qmake.super anywhere.